# How to cover all columns in sdblock used in UML diagram

Tags: pgf-umlsd

In following code, the `sdblock` block  covers only  two columns (b and m). How to let the block cover all columns i.e., columns s, b, m and a.

```
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newinst {s} {S}
        \newinst {b} {B}
        \newinst {m} {M}
        \newinst {a} {A}

        \begin{sdblock}{BLOCK}{}
        \begin{messcall}{b} {TEXT}  {m} \end{messcall}          
        \end{sdblock}

    \end{sequencediagram}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by adding something like `\path (inst1.west) -- (inst4.east);` at the start of the `sdblock` environment. This works because the  block is drawn using the `east` and `west` anchors of the `current bounding box` as a reference, and by adding that `\path` the bounding box becomes wider. Every `\newinst` makes a new node named `inst<countervalue>`, so in your case the leftmost is called `inst1` and the rightmost `inst4`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{sequencediagram}
        \newinst {s} {S}
        \newinst {b} {B}
        \newinst {m} {M}
        \newinst {a} {A}

        \begin{sdblock}{BLOCK}{}
        \path (inst1.west) -- (inst4.east);
        \begin{messcall}{b} {TEXT}  {m} \end{messcall}          
        \end{sdblock}

    \end{sequencediagram}
\end{document}
```